# Jquery Live Preview in Text Area with function

Tags: jquery

I have here my code that when i click a div it will insert to textarea and it will show its preview. The content that will be inserted in textarea is image but it doest show the image live instead it needs to type a character on textarea.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.image').click(function(e){
    var tav    = $('#image_code').val(),
        strPos = $('#image_code')[0].selectionStart;
        front  = (tav).substring(0,strPos),
        back   = (tav).substring(strPos,tav.length); 
        $('#image_code').val(front + '<img src=\"' + $(this).attr("alt") + '\">' + back);
});
$('#image_code').keyup(function() {
   $('#image_preview').html( $(this).val() );
 });
});
</script>

<textarea id="image_code"></textarea>
<div id="image_preview"></div>

<div id="1" class="image" title="1" alt="http://xxxx.jpg">1</div>
<div id="2" class="image" title="2" alt="http://xxxx.jpg">2</div>
<div id="3" class="image" title="3" alt="http://xxxx.jpg">3</div>
<div id="4" class="image" title="4" alt="http://xxxx.jpg">4</div>
<div id="5" class="image" title="5" alt="http://xxxx.jpg">5</div>
```

Please Help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What happens when you try it?

Comment: I doest show the preview when i click the div but the text is inserting in textarea.

Comment: Which div? There are six in your code. Which text is inserted, and when? What do you want to happen when someone clicks the div? What do you want to happen when someone types in the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to insert an image inside the `textarea` then I'm afraid you can't: they're only designed to handle text (WYSIWYG editors use trickery to get around this).

Instead, you could use a `contenteditable` div, or try setting a background image... but the image won't be an actual physical element within the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event after the setting the value of the textarea.

```
$('#image_code').val(front + '<img src=\"' + $(this).attr("alt") + '\">' + back).trigger('keyup')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VXhMS/)

Comment: Thanks but how to move the tag img src on line 
        $('#image_preview').html( $(this).val() );

Comment: @FilipinoAutoliker what do you mean?

Comment: I dont like to show the tag "<img src="xx.jpg">" on text area. But the image will show on preview.

Comment: then what should be displayed inthe textarea

Comment: @FilipinoAutoliker whether the textarea will contain any other content other than the value of `alt`

Comment: What i mean is when i click the div 1 it will write on the textarea "1" then on the preview it will write <div id="1"></div> what i mean is that. Thanks!

Comment: @FilipinoAutoliker if the value is changes in the textarea you want it to be reflected in the preview right

Comment: @ArjunPJohny Yes. What i mean is that. Thanks!